# iOS 11.3 AND Xcode 9.3 causing Obj-C app launch failures

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

So this is an odd one... we have an application that is written in Obj-C and prior to anyone updating to iOS 11.3 it ran fine. The 11.3 update broke it... however with Xcode 9.3 and the new compiler we get the same error on any and all devices. So it appears that Apple broke something in the SDK.

By the same token, it seems likely that if they had actually broken something in the SDK then EVERYONE would be having this issue. So I turn to you, the SO braintrust, to help me figure this out!

*NOTE: Just to be extremely clear: this is an older app written in Obj-C, not Swift, and has been in maintenance only for some time.*

So the offending block of code is very simply this:

```
- (UINavigationController *)controllerForCategories: (NSArray *)categories titled:(NSString *)title
{
    DocumentViewController *dc = [[DocumentViewController alloc]initWithCategories:categories titled:title];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:dc];
    [self addChildViewController:nc];
    // ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS ^^ LINE
    [nc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.contentPanel addSubview:nc.view];
    nc.view.frame = self.contentPanel.bounds;
    return nc;
}
```

Now according to the Apple docs, that should be fine. If we had overridden addChildViewController() then we might have an issue, but we didn't, we're just calling the method. The argument, named 'nc', is an SDK class that extends UIViewController, so it's a valid argument to the method in question. However, on 11.3 (or on all iOS versions with Xcode 9.3, we get this error EVERY TIME we launch, on any device:

> 2018-04-25 14:42:18.792216-0700 Steri-Vac GS[1090:855706]
>   -[MasterNavigationViewController _viewControllerSubtreeDidGainViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101210100 2018-04-25 14:42:18.792662-0700 Steri-Vac
>   GS[1090:855706] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MasterNavigationViewController
>   _viewControllerSubtreeDidGainViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101210100'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x186c4b164 0x185e94528 0x186c58628 0x1905c6188 0x186c50b10 0x186b35ccc 0x19029a964 0x19029d2c0
>   0x100a4941c 0x100a48bec 0x190205a00 0x1902055d8 0x19020c1a4
>   0x190209404 0x1902782e8 0x100a77a24 0x1902742c4 0x190465bc4
>   0x19046aa14 0x1907062a8 0x1909de100 0x190705f0c 0x19070676c
>   0x190e8b7c0 0x190e8b664 0x190bf92cc 0x190d923cc 0x190bf917c
>   0x1909dd760 0x190469158 0x19087edbc 0x18930e1f0 0x189316af8
>   0x100bb928c 0x100bc59e4 0x1893427f8 0x18934249c 0x189342a38
>   0x186bf377c 0x186bf36fc 0x186bf2f84 0x186bf0b5c 0x186b10c58
>   0x1889bcf84 0x1902695c4 0x100a51994 0x18663056c) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I've filed a bug with Apple and submitted code to support it, but I thought I'd check with the brain trust here to see if anyone had anything I could look into in the mean time. For now our app is useless and 40% of my field service techs have already updated to 11.3, so it's getting to be a critical issue for us.

Thanks in advance, folks!

Comment: Is your intent really to add a `UINavigationController` as a *childViewController* of another `UINavigationController`? And to add its *view* as a subview? Or... is `MasterNavigationViewController` not a navigation controller?

Comment: I inherited the app and don't know it all that well, but I can tell you that it's a very hierarchical expert system for troubleshooting industrial systems, so it has lot of various sub-nav trees that follow testing/troubleshooting flow charts. I also know it worked correctly before 11.3, so it's a reasonable assumption that yes, actually, we want to add nav controllers as subviews of the main view controller.

Comment: OK - not sure what to look at... Quick test, where `self` is a `UIViewController` subclass, and `DocumentViewController` is also a basic `UIViewController` subclass, your code runs fine for me -- putting the navController's view (including nav bar and `dc` as its `root`) into a `contentPanel` `UIView`. Wonder if the error is a red-herring?

Comment: What type of object is `MasterNavigationViewController ` ?

Comment: Check is `addChildViewController` get called in main thread

Comment: @jrypkahauer did u found the solution?

Comment: Yep... see my answer below... turns out it was a naming collision. In Xcode 9.4 and iOS 11.3, navigationController is a used by the API, so I just had to do a find/replace from navigationController to navController and everything was fine.

It's  no wonder it had everyone pulling their hair out, it was a weird issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple responded to my bug!

It turns out that our class  was extending the UIViewController and implementing a property called navigationController which was another instance of UIViewController, while at the same time UIViewController HAS a property called navigationController... is an instance of UINavigationController. The trick was to simply rename our navigationController to navController. Conflict resolved.

The real question is why this only stopped working after updating to Xcode 9.3 and didn’t actually break the app till our users updated to iOS 11.3. Under 11.2 the original app ran fine. And after updating to Xcode 9.3 the compiles app wouldn’t run on any version of iOS.

VERY strange!