# Application Crash on ios11 & Xcode 9: while adding [self addChildViewController:]

Tags: objective-c, ios11, xcode9

While adding child viewcontroller, I am getting following crash,
Here NavigationViewController is extended from UIViewController.

This error is coming when I `upgraded` to `Xcode 9`, working successfully on earlier versions of Xcode.

I referred the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104797/ios-11-3-and-xcode-9-3-causing-obj-c-app-launch-failures) but not getting any satisfied answer, please help me out this,

Thanx in advance. :)

**The block of code is:**

```
 _mainSectionsController = [[[MainSectionsController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self addChildViewController:_mainSectionsController];   

**Init method of _mainSectionsController** .

 -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
 {
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (!self) return nil;
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
  self.viewControllers = @
  [
   [[[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]
    autorelease]
  ];
  return self;
 } 

**init method of NavigationViewController**

 -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle: (NSBundle*)nibBundleOrNil
    {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (!self) return nil;
     self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;

    _navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    _navController.get().delegate = self;
    _navController.get().navigationBarHidden = YES;
    _navController.get().view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _navController.get().view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
    return self;
 }
```

> 2018-05-22 10:46:23.112290+0530 [912:19925] -[NavigationViewController _viewControllerSubtreeDidGainViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91ba83c000
>   2018-05-22 10:46:24.939903+0530 [912:19925] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NavigationViewController _viewControllerSubtreeDidGainViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91ba83c000'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f03f12b **exceptionPreprocess + 171 . 
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e640f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f0c0024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
>       3   UIKit                               0x000000010b2cdf51 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efc1f78 ___forwarding_** + 1432
>       5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efc1958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010b246c1d -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 696
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010b26930e -[UIViewController(UIContainerViewControllerProtectedMethods) addChildViewController:] + 83
>       8                                       0x00000001058eeac3 -[MainViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 5235
>       9                                       0x00000001059876ca -[AppDelegate loadMainViewController] + 122
>       10                                      0x0000000105984561 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1137
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010b091bca -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 299
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010b093648 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4113
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010b098aeb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010b4626f8 **111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010b8384c8 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
>       16  UIKit                               0x000000010b4622f1 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249
>       17  UIKit                               0x000000010b462b6b -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 696
>       18  UIKit                               0x000000010bde0a69 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262
>       19  UIKit                               0x000000010bde0922 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
>       20  UIKit                               0x000000010babd9c8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
>       21  UIKit                               0x000000010bcbcb06 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
>       22  UIKit                               0x000000010babd88b -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231
>       23  UIKit                               0x000000010b837b25 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
>       24  UIKit                               0x000000010b09736a -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523
>       25  UIKit                               0x000000010b672605 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369
>       26  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116cb8cc0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338
>       27  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116cc17b5 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235
>       28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f87b33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f8809f3 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
>       30  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116ced498 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
>       31  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116ced14e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464
>       32  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116ced6bd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
>       33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efe2101 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f081f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
>       35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efc6a19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
>       36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efc5fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
>       37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efc5889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
>       38  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fed99c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       39  UIKit                               0x000000010b09a5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       40                   0x000000010590c331 main + 65
>       41  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f8f7d81 start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace, and if it prints the file names and line numbers - also the source code around those line numbers would be helpful.

Comment: @battlmonstr Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `autorelease` in your `MainSectionsController` code I assume that you don't use ARC there. I highly recommend upgrading the code of `MainSectionsController` and `NavigationViewController` to ARC. This prevents accidental overreleases that might cause issues like this one.

In addition I'd recommend to move `self.viewControllers` assignment from the constructor to viewDidLoad if possible.

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much :)
Problem solved when i moved self.viewControllers assignment from the constructor to viewDidLoad.